# Term::ReadKey::GetTermialSize on MSWin32 OS

Tags: windows, perl, terminal, console, resize

When I call this script on a Linux OS [Term::Size::Any](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term%3a%3aSize%3a%3aAny) (`chars`) and [Term::ReadKey](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term%3a%3aReadKey) (`GetTerminalSize`)  return always the same number of columns.

When I call the script on a Windows machine the returned number of columns differ as soon as I resize the terminal with the mouse to a smaller size. `chars` returns the new width while `GetTerminalSize` returns the initial terminal width.

Is there a trick to get from `GetTerminalSize` the new resized terminal width?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.0;

use Term::Size::Any qw(chars);
use Term::ReadKey qw(GetTerminalSize);


say( ( chars( \*STDOUT ) )[0] );
say( ( GetTerminalSize( \*STDOUT ) )[0] );
```

Comment: Are you resizing and getting a scrollbar, or actually changing the windows' size via the properties, they are not the same "thing"

Comment: How I resize the terminal: I move the mouse to the bottom right corner of the Console, then I press the left mouse button and then I move the mouse to the left - while keeping pressed the left mouse button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are currently doing is not called "resizing", the terminal screen size is still the same, you are just diminishing the terminal visible size.

To change the Window Terminal "size", click on the top left corner, go to Properties change the "Screen Buffer Size", at the moment you are just changing the "Window Size"

Comment: I'm only interested in the visible part (without scrolling). `Term::Size::Any` does what I need when writing something portable. But sometimes I have to load `Term::ReadKey` anyway and then I had could use `GetTerminalSize`.